# pgmm function and gmm function in R

Tags: r, plm, gmm

I have a very basic question regarding these two functions in R.

When I try to do panel data analysis using generalised moment method, I realised that both gmm and pgmm are functions for this method. What is the difference between them? Should I use pgmm one instead of gmm for panel data(I would like to do difference GMM estimation)?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are doing panel analysis, you should use `pgmm`. It is part of the `plm` package for `R`, which is a comprehensive package for panel data econometrics.

I assume the `gmm` function you refer to is from the package of the same name. It is developed for cross-section GMM estimation, not panel data.

Comment: Oh ok! So I will use pgmm for panel analysis. Thank you so much!